# how to get the current user domain in serverside while using form authentication?

Tags: asp.net

I have an Application where i need to find the current Log in Users Domain name  in the server site, but my authentication mode is Form, kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i thought a nice way of solving the problem, and got it done too.

**By using JS we can get the current system details then store it into a hidden filed and we can access the current system domain name & user name in the server side.**

```
 function domain_Data() {
                var comdetails = new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell");
                var comusername = comdetails.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%");
                var comusername1 = comdetails.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserDomain%");

                var add = comusername1 + ":" + comusername;
                alert(add);
                document.getElementById("_hide").value = add;}
```

Comment: Problem here is that what if ActiveX is disabled? Then you are screwed :). Question is, what exactly are you trying to achieve here? What is the reasoning for having forms auth and wanting t oget the domain user account?

Comment: i have mentioned it on the question, need to get the user name and domain name of current user in server side..and my authentication mode is"FORM", by this one i completed the task.if disabled then  need to think differently..

Comment: you have not mentioned the REASON for doing this.

Comment: This is not a hacking :) ...

The application requirement was to check weather the user who is login from the specified system(in organization) , is it the same person?we have LDAP check all those things, thus here we need to retrive the user details and make it check with the LDAP return values

Comment: right but in such a case, why use forms authentication? why not directly use Windows authentication?

Comment: yup, i had developed it in windows it self, but sometimes requirement is that kind we can't change it.i searched all technique nothing worked for me and finally i used this process after a long thinking.if you have any way to do it in form Authentication then that' ll be nice.